# Why is my pthread program missing prime numbers?

Tags: c, pthreads

I am working on a program that utilizes pthreads in C. The function of the thread is to compute prime numbers based on a maximum number entered by the user at the CLI. Thus say for instance, the user enters `./ComputePrimes 20`, the output should be `2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19`.

However, for some reason, my program only outputs 2 to 13 (thus my output is `2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13`).

I am using a formula based off of Wilson's Theorem for computing primes:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes

I know from a Discrete Mathematics class I have taken in the past that there is no solid formula for computing primes. The purpose of this program however is to demonstrate pthreads which I believe I have done successfully. Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>


void *generatePrimeNumbers(void *primenum) {
    int  i, j, a, b;
    int primeNumbers[] = {};
    int limit = (int *)primenum;

    for (i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
           j = 0;
           int a = (factorial(i) % (i + 1));
           int b =  (i - 1) + 2;
           if (((a / i) * b) != 0) {
               primeNumbers[j] = ((a / i) * b);
               printf("%d ", primeNumbers[j]);
               j++;
           }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return NULL;
}

int factorial(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else return n * factorial(n - 1);

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int numLimit;
    pthread_t primethread;
    if (argc != 2) {
       printf("You need to enter a valid number!\n");
       exit(-1);
   }
   else {
       int i = 0;
       numLimit = atoi(argv[1]);
       if (numLimit < 2) {
               printf("Please enter a number greater than or equal to 2.\n");
               exit(-1);
       }
   }

     pthread_create(&primethread, NULL, generatePrimeNumbers, (void *)numLimit);
     pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

As you can see below, I successfully create a thread, however some of the prime numbers are missing. I believe that I might have messed up somewhere in my called threads function. Thanks!

Comment: If you run your function without the thread does it work? `int primeNumbers[] = {};` declares an array with 0 length. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: Note that in general `sizeof(int) != sizeof(void *)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many environment, `int` can only store integers only upto 2147483647 (2**31 - 1) while `20! = 2432902008176640000`. Therefore, `factorial(20)` cannot be calculated correctly.

Making the return type of `factorial` to `long long` will make the output for input 20 correct (supposing that `long long` can save upto 2**63 - 1), but for larger number, you should consider other method such as taking modulo inside `factorial` method before the number gets too big.

Also note that the line

```
int limit = (int *)primenum;
```

looks weird. The cast should be `int`, not `int *`.

Another point is that you are assigning numbers to 0-element array as Retired Ninja said.
In this code, `primeNumbers` isn't used other than the printing point, so the printing should be done directly like

```
printf("%d ", ((a / i) * b));
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I'm not very used to C, I am more accustomed to Java. I know this sounds bad, but this is for an Operating Systems class. Thanks again, I'll try changing the return type of my factorial function.

Comment: MikeCAT, I made the changes that you suggested to my threads program, however I am running into some minor conundrums. When attempting to compute prime numbers up to 100, the following is displayed: Algebra@Ubuntu:~/Documents/OperatingSystems/ProgrammingProjects/ $ ./PrimeNumbers 100The prime numbers of a given number 100 are: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 -23 35

Comment: It should be displaying more numbers than that. It is probably a data declaration somewhere.

Comment: @Al-geBra [This code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/T33Z6vGZGr9CcSRd) worked without misssing prime numbers up to 100. I forgot to mention that you should declare (or define) functions *before* using them.

Comment: MikeCAT, you are right, I actually fixed that without telling you about it. However, I noticed one significant difference. That is, the difference between our factorial functions. I thought I covered all base cases and had the right formula but you added another parameter. I'm a bit confused. Maybe I should walk away from the computer for a bit.

Comment: @Al-geBra This is the "other method" I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: MikeCAT, got it I completely understand after re-reading your answer. Although syntactically C and Java share a lot of similarities, the more and more I program in C, I am beginning to understand how different the two languages are.